# video player that runs videos from pointed directory and updates list of files to play while new file appears in directory

Tags: video, playlist

I am not sure if this community is good place to ask, anyway i will try.

I am looking for a video player that has an option to play files from directory, but each time i copy a new file to directory it will automatically update its playlist to play also new file that came into directory. Quite simple but couldn find any software that is constantly looking into directory or at least once every video ends. I use windows 7, 8 or 10.
Any advice?

Kalreg.

Comment: If you're able to use shell scripts ffplay could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Serviio is really good. It has a free and paid option. The free version is great.

http://serviio.org/